# netbeans can't find dot in path

Tags: netbeans

I have a maven project. I am using umlgraph to generate a graph. I have installed graphviz and is present in path.

But when i try to run mvn javadoc:javadoc, netbeans complains

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "dot":
```

Is there a way i can specify the path of dot.exe to maven or to netbeans.

I did not install netbeans. its a OS independent zip file. I looked into netbeans.conf but not sure how to specify the path to dot.exe over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not run the "dot.exe" application from Maven using the `mvn javadoc:javadoc` goal. You may be able to use GraphViz, if "dot.exe" command is running separately.

I would suggest looking at the [jDepend plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/32365/jdepend-plugin) for NetBeans 7.1 and 7.2, or checking out [Visualizing NetBeans Module Dependencies](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/visualizing_netbeans_module_dependencies) to see if this can help you. If your current progress is halted.